# Is there a way to edit database values within controller mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using controller to try and edit values within the database.

```
public ActionResult test(String t, String s)
{
    if (t!= null)
    {
        if (radio_select == "s")
        {
            if (s!= null)
            {
               // I want to know how to edit my database values here.  
            }
        }
    }
    return View();
}
```

Below is my database

[image]

I want to Edit these values from  9 -> 10 and 19 -> 20 . And Do this in controller.

Comment: Sorry what I meant is edit my values stored in my database, and I want to do this within my controller and not view

Comment: So what are you having problems with? There is nothing in your code which gives any indication of what you want to actually do.

Comment: I have edit my question seen above

Comment: Then get the item from the database - e.g. `var item = db.yourTable.where(x => x.Id = 2).FirstOrDefault();` then update the values and save the item.

Comment: Will try that cheers !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To edit a record, you need to select a record first.To select a record, you need a unique id.

The below code will update your record to the new value.

```
//  The id and new values are hard coded here. 
//  You might want to get it from the view as your action method parameters
//  or somewhere else.

  var id = 2;
  var responseBitNewValue = 10;
  var frequencyNewValue = 19;

  var db = new YourDbContext();
  var entityItem = db.Responses.FirstOrDefault(s=>s.Id==id);
  if(entityItem !=null)
  {
      entityItem.response_bit = responseBitNewValue ;
      entityItem.frequency = frequencyNewValue ;

      db.Entry(entityItem).State = EntityState.Modified;
      db.SaveChanges();
  }
```

Assuming `YourDbContext` is the name of your db context class and `Responses` is a property on that ( which is a collection of entities representing your table record)l

Answer (score 0):

First of all, yes, this is entirely possible and in fact is the case for edit and create links.

You will need to add a model to your project, you can then use that and entity framework to update your database.  See [this tutorial from MS](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/accessing-your-models-data-from-a-controller).

In fact you should always be making changes to your database from within a controller and never from within a view.